# Convert the function into series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

I have the function
$$
f(z)={\frac{z}{z^2-2z+5}}, z_0=1
$$
i.e. I need to have it in form $f(z)={\sum{C_k(z-z_0)^n}}={\sum{C_k(z-1)^n}}$

I do
$$
z-1=t, z=t+1,
$$
$$
{\phi}(t)=f(t+1)={\frac{t+1}{(t+1)^2-2(t+1)+5}}={\frac{t+1}{t^2+2t+1-2t-2+5}}
={\frac{t+1}{t^2+4}}$$
I don't get how to continue from here. Usually I get something in the form $1+{\frac{C}{g(t)}}$ and try to use it, but here I don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
One way is writing your result as geometric series
$$\dfrac{1}{4+t^2}=\dfrac{1/4}{1+(\frac{t}{2})^2}=\dfrac14\left(1-\dfrac{t^2}{4}+\dfrac{t^4}{16}-\dfrac{t^6}{64}+\cdots\right)$$
where $|t|<2$.

**Edit:**
$$\dfrac{t+1}{4+t^2}=\dfrac14\left[\left(1-\dfrac{t^2}{4}+\dfrac{t^4}{16}-\dfrac{t^6}{64}+\cdots\right)+t\left(1-\dfrac{t^2}{4}+\dfrac{t^4}{16}-\dfrac{t^6}{64}+\cdots\right)\right]$$
$$=\dfrac14\left[1-\dfrac{t^2}{4}+\dfrac{t^4}{16}-\dfrac{t^6}{64}+\cdots+t-\dfrac{t^3}{4}+\dfrac{t^5}{16}-\dfrac{t^7}{64}+\cdots\right]$$
$$=\dfrac14+\dfrac{t}{4}-\dfrac{t^2}{16}-\dfrac{t^3}{16}+\dfrac{t^4}{64}+\dfrac{t^5}{64}\pm\cdots$$

Comment: but I have $${\frac{t+1}{t^2+4}}$$ which expands to $${\frac{1}{t+{\frac{4}{t}}}}+{\frac{1}{t^2+4}}$$. What do I do with the first fraction?

Comment: So find $(t+1)\times\dfrac{1}{4+t^2}$..

Comment: Like this?
$$
... = (t+1)\times {\sum{(-1)^k * {\frac{t^{2k}}{4^k}}}}
$$

Comment: yes, it is .....

Comment: then what? I'm not fluent in solving these, I'm just starting...